# Test for List<T> membership using a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Does anyone know if there is a way to test for list membership utilizing a list. For example I have a class named Membership which has a property Rebates which is of type `List<Enums.RebateType>`. I want to test using a lambda expression to see if that list contains any rebates that are of a specific type. My orginal lambda expression is as follows

```
return Membership.Rebates.Exists(rebate =>
    rebate.RebateType == Enums.RebateType.A &&
    rebate.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved);
```

Instead of having to do the following:

```
return Membership.Rebates.Exists(rebate =>
   (rebate.RebateType == Enums.RebateType.A &&
    rebate.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved) ||
   (rebate.RebateType == Enums.RebateType.B &&
    rebate.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved));
```

I was wondering if something similar to the following mocked up SQL syntax could be done via one Lambda expression.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Membership.Rebates
WHERE RebateType IN (ValidRebateTypes) AND Approved = true
```

ValidRebateTypes is curently a `List<Enums.RebateType>` that I am testing for i.e. ValidRebateTypes = (Enums.RebateType.A, Enums.RebateType.B).

The work around I currently have is as follows:

```
bool exists = false;
foreach (Enums.RebateType rebateType in ValidRebateTypes())
{
    exists =  Membership.Rebates.Exists(
                rebate =>
                rebate.RebateType == rebateType &&
                rebate.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved);
    if (exists) { break; }
}
return exists;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want:

```
Membership.Rebates.Where(r => ValidRebateTypes.Contains(r.RebateType)
                              && r.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved);
```

You can then use .Count() for the count:

```
Membership.Rebates.Where(r => ValidRebateTypes.Contains(r.RebateType) 
                              && r.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved)
                  .Count();
```

Or .Any() to determine the existence of any that satisfy that condition

```
Membership.Rebates.Any(r => ValidRebateTypes.Contains(r.RebateType) 
                            && r.RebateStatus == Enums.RebateStatus.Approved);
```

Comment: If all he wants is to know if it exists (not the count) then use `.Any()` instead of `.Count()`, so it can quit at the first match instead of going through the whole shebang.

Comment: Good catch, I was simply duplicating his SQL.

Comment: Or just replace Where with Any and lose the Count altogether.

Comment: Edited to consolidate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marc's suggestion, I would recomment making `ValidRebateTypes` a `HashSet<Enums.RebateType>`.  Not only is this likely to be more efficient (although possibly not for a small set), it also reveals your intent (ie. that there only be one of each value of `RebateType` in it).